# Angular 8: Arrange array sequences by hour

Tags: arrays, angular, sequence

I have an array like

```
array: [
{hour: 3pm, data:[]},
{hour: 8am, data:[]},
{hour: 9am, data:[]},
{hour: 12pm, data:[]},
{hour: 2pm, data:[]},
{hour: 10am, data:[]},
{hour: 1pm, data:[]},
{hour: 11am, data:[]},
];
```

I want it arrange in ascending sequence by hour like

```
array: [
{hour: 8am, data:[]},
{hour: 9am, data:[]},
{hour: 10am, data:[]},
{hour: 11am, data:[]},
{hour: 12pm, data:[]},
{hour: 1pm, data:[]},
{hour: 2pm, data:[]},
{hour: 3pm, data:[]},
];
```

I tried using sort, but the result I get was

```
array:[
{hour:08, data:[]},
{hour:09, data:[]},
...
];
```

I want the hour remain in 8am, 9am and so on.
is there anyway to do it?

Comment: your array have 7 objects while expected results have 8 object. can you please check and correct this ?

Comment: sorry, my faults, correced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this reference from @GabrielBiga

Working Example : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d21sqj)

```
this.array.sort((a, b) => {
      let time1 = parseInt(a.hour);
      let time2 = parseInt(b.hour);
      if (a.hour.match(/.*pm/) && time1 < 12) time1 += 12;
      else if (a.hour.match(/.*am/) && time1 == 12) time1 = 0;

      if (b.hour.match(/.*pm/) && time2 < 12) time2 += 12;
      else if (b.hour.match(/.*am/) && time2 == 12) time2 = 0;

      if (time1 < time2) return -1;
      if (time1 > time2) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

```
let x = [
    {hour: '3pm', data:[]},
    {hour: '8am', data:[]},
    {hour: '9am', data:[]},
    {hour: '12pm', data:[]},
    {hour: '2pm', data:[]},
    {hour: '10am', data:[]},
    {hour: '1pm', data:[]} 
]; 

let final = x.sort((a, b) => {
    let time1 = parseInt(a.hour);
    let time2 = parseInt(b.hour);
    if(a.hour.match(/.*pm/)) time1 += 12; 
    if(b.hour.match(/.*pm/)) time2 += 12;
    if (time1 < time2) return -1;
    if (time1 > time2) return 1;
    return 0; 
});

console.log(final);
```

Comment: tried, but not working, used ur code, but the result that I get is not what I want, the result I get from ur code is
```
array: [{hour:08, data:[]},{hour:09, data:[]} ...];
```
what I want is 
```
array: [{hour:8am, data:[]}, {hour:9am, data:[]}...];
```

Comment: 12 am and 12 pm will sort wrong, as 12 am will be considered as 12 and 12 pm will be considered as 24

Answer (score 0):

Add a new property *fullhour*:

```
this.array.forEach(x => {
    const time = parseInt(a.hour);
    x.fullhour = a.hour.indexOf('pm') >= 0 ? time + 12 : time;
})
```

then sort by *fullhour.*

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own sort function like this:

```js
const times = [
    {hour: '3pm', data:[]},
    {hour: '8am', data:[]},
    {hour: '9am', data:[]},
    {hour: '12pm', data:[]},
    {hour: '12am', data:[]}, // Added for example
    {hour: '2pm', data:[]},
    {hour: '10am', data:[]},
    {hour: '1pm', data:[]} 
];

const toFullHour = hour => {
  let fullHour = parseInt(hour);

  if (fullHour === 12) fullHour = 0;
  if (~hour.indexOf('pm')) fullHour += 12;

  return fullHour;
};
times.sort((a, b) => toFullHour(a.hour) - toFullHour(b.hour));

console.log(times);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "hour": "12am",
    "data": []
  },
  {
    "hour": "8am",
    "data": []
  },
  {
    "hour": "9am",
    "data": []
  },
  {
    "hour": "10am",
    "data": []
  },
  {
    "hour": "12pm",
    "data": []
  },
  {
    "hour": "1pm",
    "data": []
  },
  {
    "hour": "2pm",
    "data": []
  },
  {
    "hour": "3pm",
    "data": []
  }
]
```